# how to duplicate each row of a matrix N times Numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, duplicates, row

I have a matrix with these dimensions (150,2) and I want to duplicate each row N times. I show what I mean with an example.

Input:

```
a = [[2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 9]]
```

suppose N= 3, I want this output:

```
[[2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [5 6]
 [5 6]
 [5 6]
 [7 9]
 [7 9]
 [7 9]]
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can you please edit your sample data, right now it does not make much sense.

Comment: I think your example `a` should be `a = [[2, 3], [5, 6], [7, 9]]`.

Comment: I've posted a picture I hope will make it clear :)  a is a column array

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) with parameter `axis=0` as:

```
a = np.array([[2, 3],[5, 6],[7, 9]])

print(a)
[[2 3]
 [5 6]
 [7 9]]

r_a = np.repeat(a, repeats=3, axis=0)

print(r_a)
[[2 3]
 [2 3]
 [2 3]
 [5 6]
 [5 6]
 [5 6]
 [7 9]
 [7 9]
 [7 9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input is a vector, use `atleast_2d` first.

```
a = np.atleast_2d([2, 3]).repeat(repeats=3, axis=0)
print(a)

# [[2 3]
#  [2 3]
#  [2 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

To create an empty multidimensional array in NumPy (e.g. a 2D array m*n to store your matrix), in case you don't know m how many rows you will append and don't care about the computational cost Stephen Simmons mentioned (namely re-building the array at each append), you can squeeze to 0 the dimension to which you want to append to: `X = np.empty(shape=[0, n])`.

This way you can use for example (here `m = 5` which we assume we didn't know when creating the empty matrix, and `n = 2`):

```
import numpy as np

n = 2
X = np.empty(shape=[0, n])

for i in range(5):
    for j  in range(2):
        X = np.append(X, [[i, j]], axis=0)

print X
```

which will give you:

```
[[ 0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.]
 [ 1.  0.]
 [ 1.  1.]
 [ 2.  0.]
 [ 2.  1.]
 [ 3.  0.]
 [ 3.  1.]
 [ 4.  0.]
 [ 4.  1.]]
```